# Neo4j Cypher RegExp ignore case query doesn't work on non-Latin characters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Sometimes I have to search nodes by RegExp ignore case query and it doesn't work on non-Latin characters.

For example I have a `node.name property = ЖК Львівський маєток`

If I search by

```
name =~ (?i).*ЖК Львівський маєток.*
```

everything is working fine

but in case of

```
name =~ (?i).*жк Львівський маєток.*
```

it doesn't search the node.

By the way - on Latin characters everything is working fine.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Hi! Your two lines of code are equals...

Comment: Hi, no, the second line contains `жк` in lower case

Comment: Right. My mistake!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need a few minutes to test your solution and in case of success I will accept the answer. Thanks again !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add an 'u' in your regex to transform it in a case-insensitive unicode regex. Like this:

```
name =~ (?ui).*ЖК Львівський маєток.*
```